# Process - child or grandchild?

Tags: c, process, fork

I have this part of my code , runs smoothly but I can't figure out if the second process that is created is a grandchild of the first child , or just a child process . Is this :

```
if (fork() != 0)
    parent(array,N);
else {
    child1(array,N);
    if(fork() != 0) 
        child2(array,N);
}
```

same to that :

```
if (fork() != 0)
    parent(array,N);
else {
    child1(array,N);
}

if (fork() == 0)
    child2(array,N);
```

cause I'm getting the same results . The programm is having an array and parent computes the max of the fir 1/3 of the array , the 1st child the second 1/3 and the 2nd child the third . Parent gets results from pipes from the children and prints them . Runs the same for the 2 versions I exhibit above .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int pfd1[2],pfd2[2]; // pfd[1] gia to prwto paidi , pfd[2] gia to deutero paidi

void parent(int array[],int N) {



    int i;
    int max_p;
    int child1_max,child2_max;        //auto pou 8a steilei

    max_p=array[0];      // <============================================================================

    close(pfd1[1]); //no writing by the parent
    close(pfd2[1]); //no writing by the parent

    for(i=0;i<N/3;i++) {

        if(array[i]>max_p) {
            max_p=array[i];
        }
    }

    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);   /* Wait my child process */

    read(pfd1[0],&child1_max,sizeof(int)); //get 1st child's max_c
    close(pfd1[0]);

    read(pfd2[0],&child2_max,sizeof(int)); //get 1st child's max_c
    close(pfd2[0]);

    printf("1st child_max is %d\n",child1_max); 
    printf("2nd child_max is %d\n",child2_max);
    printf("parents max is %d\n",max_p);

    /*if(max_p>child_max) {
        printf("max is %d (was in parent)\n",max_p);
        printf("max of child is %d\n",child_max);
    }else {
        printf("max is %d (was in child)\n",child_max);
        printf("max of parent is %d\n",max_p);
    }*/


}


void child1(int array[],int N) {
    int i;

    int max_c=array[N/2];    // <============================================================================

    close(pfd1[0]); // No reading by child

    for(i=N/3;i<(2*N)/3;i++) {

        if(array[i]>max_c) {
            max_c=array[i];
        }
    }

    write(pfd1[1],&max_c,sizeof(int));
    close(pfd1[1]);
}

void child2(int array[],int N) {
    int i;

    int max_c=array[(2*N)/3];  // <============================================================================

    close(pfd2[0]); // No reading by child


    for(i=(2*N)/3;i<N;i++) {

        if(array[i]>max_c) {
            max_c=array[i];
        }
    }

    write(pfd2[1],&max_c,sizeof(int));
    close(pfd2[1]); 



}

int main(void) {

    int array[]={111,1222,10,392,3211,3,2,50,8};
    int N=sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);

    //printf("\n %d \n",N);

    if (pipe(pfd1) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe()");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pipe(pfd2) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe()");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fork() != 0)
        parent(array,N);

    else {
        child1(array,N);

        //if(fork() != 0) 
        //  child2(array,N);
    }

    if (fork() == 0)
        child2(array,N);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you determine which process(es) call the second `fork`?

Comment: I think the first child ? Not sure that's why I'm asking

Comment: Well the function names you have are pretty helpful. Who calls `parent`? Who calls `child1`? Once you know that, can you figure out who calls the second `fork`?

Comment: They're all in main function

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the same results. What happens in `parent`, `child1`, and `child2`? Provide a [mcve]. Consider using a debugger or print out the pid inside each function to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Add `printf("pid = %d, parent pid = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());` at several points throughout the program and the answer will become apparent.

Comment: I tried it , guess child2 is grandchild , but i get the same for the two versions I exhibited above

Comment: Whether the two fragments are equivalent depends on whether the `parent()` function returns.  If it does not return, they're equivalent; if it does return, they are not.  When debugging multiprocess code, use `printf()` statements which report the current PID: `printf("%d: …message intended…\n", (int)getpid(), …);` (noting the newline at the end — that's important for timely diagnostics.  In case of doubt, add `fflush(stdout);` after the printing operations.  This helps you understand which process is doing what.  Immediately after `fork()`, print `getppid()` (PPID) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, these are not the same. In the second piece of code both the parent and the child created from the first `if (fork() != 0)` will call the second `if (fork() == 0)` (creating two more child processes with one being a grandchild). 
In the first piece of code, only the child created by `if (fork() != 0)` will call the second `if(fork() != 0)`. In both examples there is a grandchild process.

Also, in the first piece of code, you call `child2(array,N)` as the parent (well, as the first child). By doing this you end up forking for no reason. You should do `if (fork() == 0)` if you want the child to call `child2(array,N)` (and thus be the true grandchild). Right now, the grandchild process just exits.

Here is a tree to show the forks.
The tree for the first piece of code. Note, evert split on the tree represents a fork call. When we go up we are the child process and when we go down we are the parent of the fork. I added delays in the tree to show the waits.
[image]

The tree for the second piece of code:
[image]

The reason that you are getting the same results is because the second `child2` that gets called by the parent process happens after you print the results.

Also, in `parent` you only wait for the first child but you use results from the second child. You should also add some wait logic to `child1`.

I would suggest you use the following

```
if (fork() != 0)
    parent(array,N);
else {
    child1(array,N);
    if(fork() == 0) 
        child2(array,N);
}
```

This has the following tree.
[image]

Here, `child2` is called as the grandchild process.

Comment: yes this is the one I chose also , after using the prints to see what was happening > also the diagrams are very helpful ty

Answer (score 2):

In the first example we have the following processes:

```
Parent
    parent()
    Child
        child1()
        child2()
        Grandchild
            Doesn't so anything
```

because the second `fork()` is being done in the child process. It then calls `child2()` when the result is non-zero, which means it's the same process that called `fork()`. Since there's no `else` block to the second `if`, the grandchild doesn't run any code (actually, it will run the code that follows everything you posted).

The second example has the following:

```
Parent
    parent()
    Child 1
        child1()
    Child 2
        child2()
```

In this case, the second `fork()` is executed in the original process.

Also, if `child1()` doesn't exit the process, the Child 1 process will continue executing after the first `if/else` is done, so it will *also* execute the second `fork()`. You'll then get the following:

```
Parent
    parent()
    Child 1
        child1()
        Grandchild
            child2()
    Child 2
        child2()
```